updateSelectInput not working inside a observeEvent
I am trying to clear a selection in a Shiny app in R programming, so that when I do it my selections go back to NULL or an empty string, and my map can identify that it clear so it should go back to default values. But when I select the clear group, the values in the select input stay the same, they don't update and I'm not sure about why.
I don't understand whats missing in the update, everything else works accordingly except that part. What I wish to do is when the action button is pressed, the print() should be the selected value "".
This is the code I'm currently using:
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(DT)
library(shinythemes)
library(shinyWidgets)y
#sample data frame
tabla_filtro_pais <- data.frame(PAIS=c("México", "México", "México", "Brasil", "México", 
                                       "México", "México", "Colombia", "México", "México",
                                       "México", "México", "México", "México", "México", 
                                       "México", "México", "México", "México", "México", 
                                       "México", "México", "México", "México", "México"),
                                ENTIDAD=c("Jalisco", "Nuevo León", "México", "São Paulo",
                                          "Puebla", "Jalisco", "Puebla", "Antioquia", 
                                          "Jalisco", "Sonora", "Coahuila De Zaragoza", 
                                          "Ciudad De México", "Baja California Sur", 
                                          "Hidalgo", "Nuevo León", "Oaxaca", 
                                          "Veracruz Ignacio De La Llave","Nuevo León", 
                                          "Michoacán De Ocampo", "Yucatán", 
                                          "Puebla", "Hidalgo", "Sinaloa", "Chiapas", "México"),
                                Municipio=c("La Manzanilla De La Paz", "General Bravo", 
                                            "Temoaya", "Cajamar", "Cuautinchán", "Tequila", 
                                            "Teteles De Ávila Castillo", "Sabaneta", "Juchitlán",
                                            "Guaymas", "Matamoros", "Cuauhtémoc", "Loreto", 
                                            "Atotonilco De Tula", "Los Ramones", 
                                            "Santa Cruz Xoxocotlán",  "Tlilapan", "Juárez",     
                                            "Irimbo", "Kanasín", "San José Chiapa", 
                                            "Zapotlán De Juárez", "Concordia", "Suchiapa",
                                            "Temamatla"))
#ui logic
ui <- fluidPage(
  ##tipo de font
  theme = bslib::bs_theme(
    base_font = bslib::font_google("Open Sans"),
    code_font = bslib::font_google("Roboto Mono")
  ),
  ##css para personalizar la pagina
  tags$head(tags$style(
    HTML(
      "
      .navbar .navbar-nav > li > a, .navbar .navbar-brand {
        color: #953735;
      }
      .navbar, .navbar-default {
        background-color: #230206;
        border-color: #953735;
      }
      .leaflet-container {
        background: #D3D3D3;
      }
      /* Color de la tabla y contenidos */
      .dataTables_wrapper {
        color: #230206;
      }
      .shiny-input-container {
        color: #953735;
      }
      /* Custom para radio buttons */
      .btn-custom-class {
      background-color: #EADBDA; /* color de fondo */
      color: #230206; /* color de texto */
      border-color: #953735; /* color de border */
    }
    .btn-custom-class:hover {
      background-color: #D3D3D3; /* color fondo hover */
      color: #230206; /* color letra hover */
    }
    .input-group-btn {
        width: auto;
        vertical-align: middle;
      }
      .btn-xs {
        padding: 1px 5px;
        line-height: 1.2;
        margin-right: 0.5px;
        height: fit-content;
        align-self: strech;
        vertical-align: middle;
      }
      /* colores custom para los CircleMarkerClusters */
      .marker-cluster-large {
      background-color: rgba(170,26,61,0.6) !important;
      }
      .marker-cluster-large div {
      background-color: rgba(149,23,53,0.6) !important;
      }
      .marker-cluster-medium {
      background-color: rgba(202,117,140,0.6) !important;
      }
      .marker-cluster-medium div {
      background-color: rgba(187,77,106,0.6) !important;
      }
      .marker-cluster-small {
      background-color: rgba(239,209,217,0.6) !important;
      }
      .marker-cluster-small div {
      background-color: rgba(231,175,198,0.6) !important;
      }

    "
    )
  )),
  ##pestaña del mapa
  navbarPage(
    title = "Some title",
    id = "nav",
    tabPanel("Some tab name",
             fluidRow(
               column(
                 width = 3,
                 ##primer filtro "País"
                 div(
                   class = "d-flex align-items-center",
                   div(
                     ##boton para resetear el filtro
                     actionButton("resetCountry", label = "X", class = "btn btn-default btn-xs"),
                     style = 'margin-right: 1px;
                   position: relative;
                   top: 7px;'
                   ),
                   div(
                     selectInput(
                       "country",
                       "País",
                       choices = c("Seleccione" = "",
                                   "Brasil","México","Colombia"),
                       width = "280px"
                     ),
                     style = "flex:1;"
                   )
                 ),
                 ##filtro de estado para el pais
                 div(
                   class = "d-flex align-items-center",
                   ##boton para resetear el filtro
                   div(
                     actionButton("resetState", label = "X", class = "btn btn-default btn-xs"),
                     style = 'margin-right: 1px;
                   position: relative;
                   top: 7px;'
                   ),
                   div(
                     selectInput(
                       "state",
                       "Estado/Provincia/Departamento/Región",
                       choices = NULL,
                       width = "280px"
                     ),
                     style = "flex:1;"
                   )
                 ),
                 ##filtro de municipio para estado y pais
                 div(
                   class = "d-flex align-items-center",
                   div(
                     ##boton para resetear el filtro
                     actionButton("resetMunicipality", label = "X", class = "btn btn-default btn-xs"),
                     style = 'margin-right: 1px;
                   position: relative;
                   top: 7px;'
                   ),
                   div(
                     selectInput(
                       "municipality",
                       "Municipio/Provincia/Cantón/Comuna",
                       choices = NULL,
                       width = "280px"
                     ),
                     style = "flex:1;"
                   )
                 ),
                 position = "left"
               ),
               column(width = 9,
                      leafletOutput("map", height = "800px"))
             )),
  )
)
##server logic
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  ###RESET DE FILTROS USANDO EL BOTON
  # reset el filtro de pais
  observeEvent(input$resetCountry, {
    print(input$resetCountry)
    updateSelectInput(session, "country", selected = "")
    updateSelectInput(session,
                      "state",
                      choices = c("Seleccione" = ""),
                      selected = "")
    updateSelectInput(
      session,
      "municipality",
      choices = c("Seleccione" = ""),
      selected = ""
    )
    print(input$country)
    print(input$state)
    print(input$municipality)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$resetState, {
    updateSelectInput(session, "state", selected = "")
    updateSelectInput(
      session,
      "municipality",
      choices = c("Seleccione" = ""),
      selected = ""
    )
    print(input$country)
    print(input$state)
    print(input$municipality)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$resetMunicipality, {
    updateSelectInput(
      session,
      "municipality",
      choices = c("Seleccione" = ""),
      selected = ""
    )
    print(input$country)
    print(input$state)
    print(input$municipality)
  })

  # Update Dropdowns
  observeEvent(input$country, {
    if (!is.null(input$country) && input$country != "") {
      updateSelectInput(
        session,
        "state",
        choices = c("Seleccione" = "",
                    sort(##this part is ilustrative so that it shows that the select input 
                      ##on this lines are variable depending on country input
                      unique(tabla_filtro_pais$ENTIDAD[tabla_filtro_pais$PAIS == input$country]),
                      decreasing = FALSE
                    )),
        selected = ""
      )
    } else {
      updateSelectInput(session,
                        "state",
                        choices = c("Seleccione" = ""),
                        selected = "")
      updateSelectInput(
        session,
        "municipality",
        choices = c("Seleccione" = ""),
        selected = ""
      )
    }
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$state, {
    if (!is.null(input$state) && input$state != "") {
      updateSelectInput(
        session,
        "municipality",
        choices = c("Seleccione" = "",
                    sort(##this part is ilustrative so that it shows that the select input 
                      ##on this lines are variable depending on country input and state input
                      unique(tabla_filtro_pais$Municipio[tabla_filtro_pais$ENTIDAD == input$state]),
                      decreasing = FALSE
                    )),
        selected = ""
      )
    } else {
      updateSelectInput(
        session,
        "municipality",
        choices = c("Seleccione" = ""),
        selected = ""
      )
    }
  })
}


I don't know why it works, but if I change the choices = NULL to choices = c("Seleccione" = "") in the UI code for the state and municipality selectInputs then the values are re-set when the action buttons are clicked.
(You may have to click the button twice to see the value change, as I think the 3 print()s execute before the UI has updated.)

It does work!! Thank you, I was really struggling. I am adding this as the solution.
